# "Reverse" these math trig (3d game world) operations

Tags: math, trigonometry

I'm doing a mod for a game and I'm not very good with trigonometry and can't figure out how to do this despite of many attempts.

I have a vehicle in the 3D World at some position with some facing angle (z angle). I also have an object right next to it, and have it's XYZ position and rotations. I want to attach the object to the vehicle, but to attach it I need to specify the offsets relative to the vehicle, not real world pos.
This is the "vehicle coord system":
[vehicle attachment coords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQK0A.jpg)

But that's not the problem. I already have this code which does it:

```
new Float:ofx, Float:ofy, Float:ofz, Float:ofangle;
new Float:attachX, Float:attachY;
new Float:vehX, Float:vehY, Float:vehZ, Float:vehAngle;

GetVehiclePos(vehicleid, vehX, vehY, vehZ); // get vehicle XYZ pos
GetVehicleZAngle(vid, vehAngle); // get vehicle facing angle
ofx = x-vehX; // x = object's real world XYZ, vehX - vehicle's XYZ. Calculate            real world offset between object and vehicle
ofy = y-vehY;
ofz = z-vehZ;
ofangle = rz-vehAngle;
// calculate attach offsets relative to vehicle (see image above)
attachX = ofx*floatcos(vehAngle, degrees) +  ofy*floatsin(vehAngle, degrees);
attachY = -ofx*floatsin(vehAngle, degrees)+ ofy*floatcos(vehAngle, degrees);

AttachObjectToVehicle(objectid, vehicleid, attachX, attachY, ofz, rx, ry, ofangle); // attach object with calculated X, Y and angle
```

And this works great, but what I want to do now, is to "reverse" this.
I want to calculate object's real world position (so it will be in the exactly same place as it is now, but not attached)
So I have this:

```
    new Float:vehX, Float:vehY, Float:vehZ, Float:vehAngle;
GetVehiclePos(vehicleid, vehX, vehY, vehZ);
GetVehicleAngle(vehicleid, vehAngle);

new Float:objAttachX, Float:objAttachY, Float:objAttachZ, Float:objAttachRotX, Float:objAttachRotY, Float:ObjAttachRotZ);
GetAttachedObjectOffsets(objectid, objAttachX, objAttachY, objAttachZ);
GetAttachedObjectRotation(objectid, objAttachRotX, objAttachRotY, objAttachRotZ);
// now, using current vehicle position and the object's attachment offsets, somehow calculate the objects position in real world.
```

I would be glad if someone could help me in this, I guess it's really simple but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the trigonometry. All you have to do is solve a system of 2 linear equations with 2 unknowns (and 2 parameters, c and s):
X =  x * c + y * s
Y = -x * s + y * c
equivalent to (multiplying by s and c respectively):
s X =  s c x + s^2 y
c Y = -s c x + c^2 y.
Adding:
s X + c Y = s^2 y + c^2 y = y [cos^2 + sin^2 = 1]
Likewise for x:
c X =  c^2 x + s c y
s Y = -s^2 x + s c y,
yielding:
c X - s Y = c^2 x + s^2 x = x

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest if you used the vehicle transformation matrix (4 by 4 matrix) as that will have the scale, world coordinates and the rotation.

```
// example of identity matrix 
mat = [[1,0,0,0],
       [0,1,0,0],
       [0,0,1,0],
       [0,0,0,1]]
```

To make the following easier to understand I will rename the matrix array items
eg mat[0,0] becomes xAx and mat[0,1] is xAy

```
// not code just a representation of named array items
[ [ xAx,xAy,xAz,0 ]  // xA is the x axis x,y,z as scaled vector
  [ yAx,yAy,yAz,0 ]  // yA is the y axis x,y,z as scaled vector
  [ zAx,zAy,zAz,0 ]  // yA is the z axis x,y,z as scaled vector
  [ ox ,oy , oz,1 ] ]  // o is the coordinate of the local origin.
```

This hold true for all 4 by 4 matrix (apart from final view projections)

Thus you have the attach objects `pos` x,y,z position. If you have a matrix lib you would just multiply position vec with the object's matrix pos * mat to get the position.

```
localPos = {x : ?, y : ? , z : ?}; // The position of the mounted object
worldPos = {x : ?, y : ? , z : ?}; // the new calculated position we are after
// lp for localPos to save typing
// wp for worldPos
// Using the matrix named variables

wp.x = lp.x * xAx + lp.y * yAx + lp.z * zAx + ox;
wp.y = lp.x * xAy + lp.y * yAy + lp.z * zAy + oy;
wp.z = lp.x * xAz + lp.y * yAz + lp.z * zAz + oz;
```

And you have the world coordinates.

To do it using matrix arrays with vec3 as [0,0,0] and mat as 4 by 4 flat array [0,0,0...,0] 16 items long.

```
wp[0] = lp[0] * mat[0] + lp[1] * mat[4] + lp[2] * mat[8]  + mat[12];
wp[1] = lp[0] * mat[1] + lp[1] * mat[5] + lp[2] * mat[9]  + mat[13];
wp[2] = lp[0] * mat[2] + lp[1] * mat[6] + lp[2] * mat[10] + mat[14];
```

Or if you have overloaded vector and matrix multiplication then its is as simple as

```
Vector localPos = ? // get the object position in vehicle local space
Matrix mat = ? // get the local vehicle transform

Vector worldPos = localPos * mat;
```